# Using a dual-monitor PC and a MacBook to create a dual-monitor OS X development environment?

Tags: mac, mac-osx, rdp, vnc, desktop

Here’s the situation:

I have a MacBook and while I can and do connect a second monitor to it, I’d like to be able to use the larger/nicer/identical monitors connected to my PC to interact with my MacBook.  It seems like it should be possible (using some manner of VNC magic) to configure the MacBook to simulate two monitors, and to access them via VNC on my desktop PC.

Oh sure, there are alternatives...

- Hackintoshing – not so great with AMD
  CPU
- “Just deal with” the awkward MacBook-and-huge-monitor setup
- Buy a Mac Mini

...but that’s not necessarily the purpose of this site.

For those who grok my strange request – any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at ScreenRecycler, it's exactly what you want.  Can't vouch for performance since I haven't used it directly myself.

As a new user, can't post the URL, but it's what you'd expect...

-Tom

Comment: http://www.screenrecycler.com/home.html

Adding URL to help.

+1 for answer

Comment: that could make a nice presentation tool as well!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible to have a Macbook emulate 2 displays. There are some USB add-ons that give you the ability to run a 2nd monitor, but it is extra hardware that you're looking for.

You can use Synergy to access your macbook via keyboard and mouse, so you could conceivably use 3 LCDs (which i believe you already do today) 2 on the PC, and one on your Macbook, but you want dual lcd's on your macbook. I believe the only way to achieve this is with a [device like this](http://us.kensington.com/html/14499.html). You could use the same two LCD's that you use for your pc (assuming they each have dual inputs) and just switch between inputs.

I know it's not an ideal solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

There is an application called Teleport, which acts as a software KVM switch. As long as they are connected over the network you can do this.

It is Mac to Mac only, but I just thought you may find this useful in a slightly different configuration.

Check it out here: http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/

Answer (score 0):

I was using [Synergy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy_%28software%29) before, and it is awesome. Teleport takes it one step further if you're on Mac OS X. I've yet to see better.

If you're comfortable with X11/Unix stuff, there are numerous ways to accomplish the same thing via SSH/VNC/X11 mechanisms, all offering different advantages (compression, security, compatibility, etc.)